# Wacom Bamboo pen & touch S. It is a good choice?

Tags: drawing, bamboo

I am a budding illustrator, I like to draw and until now I used pens, paper and so on.
I would like to buy a Wacom Bamboo pen & touch S.

Where is the limit between "frustrating" and "satisfaction" when using a small tablet like that?

I mean, is that tablet right for me, that I do not use it to work? I can't take a decision, I fear I will not like that size, but price difference between S and M is a bit frightening. My budget is not too large.

I think there is no exact answer to my question—but there's something I can ask myself in order to take the model that is the right one.

If S size is too small when drawing, which wacom alternative can help me buy something larger?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really is quite a subjective question. I have a Bamboo Pen and Touch, and I think it's just fine, but your mileage may vary enormously.

As for your options, the Bamboo Fun is $199 (MSRP) and has a significantly larger active area. Larger Wacom tablets get rapidly more expensive, since you start getting into their professional product lineup (Cintiq and Intuos).

You could also look into other manufacturers to see if their large tablets are in your price range.